#  vim & colors from ANSI Escape Sequences: how to display in vim the same colors that are displayed with the cat command

Tags: command-line, vim, colors

Here's what I'm doing: I'm echoing through Php colors like this:

[image: shell colors]

php creates output containing ANSI escape sequences that color text when it is displayed through the shell on my terminal. You can find the php class and explanation [here](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/php-class-for-coloring-php-command-line-cli-scripts-output-php-output-colorizing-using-bash-shell-colors/).

But if I send my output to a file, and try to read it with vim it's not "colored", I just can see the special characters. Is there a way to display the colors like they are displayed in the shell?

Comment: It might help if you could mention how and with what program you are creating the file with the text in color, and how you are later trying to display it.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't precise enough. Quote my question: I'm echoing *through* **Php**. I.e. "`php -f filename`" and i'm echoing using this class here: http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/php-class-for-coloring-php-command-line-cli-scripts-output-php-output-colorizing-using-bash-shell-colors/

Comment: Possible cross site duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/358409/how-can-i-tell-vim-to-show-ansi-escape-codes-properly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The terminal output will be colored if the content of the file will be sent "as-is" to the terminal, without any modifications. However, vim and some other editors will escape meta characters in the text and instead maybe add some other color codes for their syntax highlighting, so this doesn't work.

Try dumping the file to the terminal with `cat`, this should work. Some simple editors or pagers like `less` might also work.

***Edit:***
I have not found a way to let vim "pass-through" all the escape codes, but I have found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7721) which links to this [vim script](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=302), which parses the escape codes and uses the vim syntax highlighting to recreate the color codes in the output. According to its description, it should do exactly what you want (but I have not tested it).

Comment: Is there a way to do this with vim (= precise *not* to escape)?

Comment: @OlivierPons see my edit

Comment: It didn't work with less but did work with more: cat ~/myfile.txt | more

Comment: That script kind of works. It's a vimball, so to install it, gunzip it somewhere, then in vim ':source ansi.vba'. It handles a lot of escapes but not all   - Another solution is 'less -R filename'.

Answer (score 0):

I just found that there is a Vim plugin to deal with ASCI escape characters. It is called 'Ansi Highlighting'. If you are intrested please visit http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#ANSIESC

Oh, you are going to need to use 'Vimballs' to unpack ANSIESC.